# Need help creating dropdown for menu item in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

I have a unordered list created for my menu that was automatically created by visual studios create web form template that I have been adding to as I go along. My problem is that now I have one specific link that I would like to have dropdown to other links but I cant for the life of me figure out the easiest way to do it.

Here's the code for the menu links from Site.master:

```
     <nav>
           <ul id="menu">
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/About.aspx">About</a></li>                        
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Pricing.aspx">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="VideoTransfer.aspx">Video Transfer</a></li>                     
                <li><a runat="server"href="~/Testimonials.aspx">Testimonials</a</li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
     </nav>
```

I'm trying to get "Video Transfer" and a couple other links I will later create, to appear as a vertical dropdown menu navigation of "Pricing" when a user hovers over "Pricing".

Here is the relevant CSS from Site.css:

```
/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="3">
  <Items>
   <asp:MenuItem Text="File" Value="File">
    <asp:MenuItem Text="New" Value="New"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Open" Value="Open"></asp:MenuItem>
   </asp:MenuItem>

   <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="Edit">
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Copy" Value="Copy"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Paste" Value="Paste"></asp:MenuItem>
   </asp:MenuItem>

   <asp:MenuItem Text="View" Value="View">
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Normal" Value="Normal"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Preview" Value="Preview"></asp:MenuItem>
   </asp:MenuItem>
  </Items>
 </asp:Menu>
```

Try this for Menu control.. You can change the orientation of the Menu control in the properties.

Comment: Thanks for your help now I just need to work on the CSS

Comment: Would you Want me to help?